# Store Transaction(STOW-RS) DICOM Wrong StudyInstanceUid

Tags: dicom

I have just started learning Dicom standards. In P3.18 -> [Table 10.5.1-1](https://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part18/sect_10.5.html)(Page-109). For Uri template: **/studies**, may have different Uid. So, I am guessing you have to open the file one by one and check the Uid and save it in the appropriate location.  But In case of **/studies/{study}** all will have same uid. If the sender messes up the Uid attribute what should be done. In that case I would assume that you would have 2 separate Uid, one sent in URI template and ones existing inside the file. Or is it impossible to come to this state due to some other things I do not know about Dicom standard.

Example:
Suppose, There are 4 Instances:

1st Instance -> StudyUID: S01, SeriesUID: Se01, InstanceUID: I01

2nd Instance -> StudyUID: S01, SeriesUID: Se01, InstanceUID: I02

3nd Instance -> StudyUID: S02, SeriesUID: Se02, InstanceUID: I03

4th Instance -> StudyUID: S02, SeriesUID: Se02, InstanceUID: I04

If a client send the image to **/studies** URL I am assuming files would be stored in below locations:

S01/Se01/I01

S01/Se01/I02

S02/Se02/I03

S02/Se02/I04

But If a client send the images to **/studies/{S01}** URL, will it be saved to the below locations or will it check the UID inside the Instances?

S01/Se01/I01

S01/Se01/I02

**S01**/Se02/I03

**S01**/Se02/I04

I understand the actual UID does not look the above example.

-Thank You

Comment: I do not understand what is your question. It seems a bit like you assume that a study corresponds to a file which is not the case. A study consists of multiple series, and each series can have multiple images. The attributes Series Instance UID and SOP Instance UID uniquely identify these levels of the information model. Also what do you mean by the "sender" and by "messing up the UID"? Please be a bit more verbose and provide an illustrative example, then I think there is probably a simple answer to your question

Comment: I tried to give in example of how I am thinking it works(which is probably wrong). I hope that helps make my question a little bit clear to understand. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, DICOM only defines how to do things right but it does not define how to behave if the communication partner behaves incorrectly (except for defining error code for particular situations).
So the standard does not provide an answer to the question how the receiver would behave in the case that the StudyInstanceUID in the URL does not match the StudyInstanceUID in the image. This is an implementor's decision.

For the client, this means to better behave correctly :-)

For the server, it makes sense to handle errors by the client gracefully wherever possible, so there is a chance but no guarantee that the server would recognize the mismatch and assign the sent objects to the study resource that is identified by the contents of the image.

Comment: I understood your explanation. But wouldn't it have been better just to use the /studies URL for both cases. I probably do not know the complete scenario. But I am failing to see particular use case where /studies/{S01} would be exclusively useful.

Comment: Agreed that the studies URL is idiot-proof and the studies/study URL is not. I am unable to explain why this potential pitfall was introduced in the standard.